# How many days per week shoud I train BJJ?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu

I recently started training BJJ and was wondering if training monday through friday with the weekend off is overkill?

I've been feeling sore after every class and in the morning I feel like someone just beat the crap out of me. I guess it just takes time to get used to the pace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Five days a week is a perfectly reasonable workout schedule for BJJ. Take care to keep your body running well: eat right, sleep plenty, and stay hydrated.

It will take a while to get used to 5 days a week, and some people--due to being out of shape or by not recovering properly--may need to ramp up from only 3 or 4 classes per week for a few months.

Comment: When training this hard recovery is every bit as important as training.

Answer (score 4):

BJJ 5 times a week is ok as long as you follow some golden rules.

1. Always stretch dynamically every single part of your body for at least 30 minutes. This will help to rid you of the cramps during rolls as well as muscle pain the next day.
2. Eat correctly and get enough sleep. You definitely need to consume even more calories and get some additional protein else you will drastically lose weight and feel fatigue all the time. I lost 10 kg in the first month of BJJ training. Proper diet & rest will also help decrease your recovery time.
3. Alternate between gi and no gi. Maybe 2 days gi, 1 day no gi. This will give you fingers time to recover from the strain. The worst strain i felt on my hands were them going numb for about a week.. I couldn't feel my ring finger and pinky fingers the the sides of the pinky all the way down to the wrist.
4. Remember to RICE (Rest, Ice, Compress & Elevate) any injuries like bruises and sprains. Do not use warm rubs or warm water during the first day of the injury, always use ice.

Other than that take it easy and don't too rash or impatient. Take your time to learn what your body can do and how much hammering it could take. After awhile you can easily go twice a day and 5 times a week.

Cheers and Keep it Up :)

Answer (score 3):

A better question would be "how many days per week is too much?". If you're out of shape, 5 days per week isn't going to do you any good and may even be counter-productive. If you still feel tired after a good night's sleep, you are training too much and need to cut back until you're in better shape. This goes for every sport ever. If you over train, your body shuts down in an attempt to keep you from hurting yourself. You need to give your muscles time to recuperate and heal. If you insist on training 5 days a week, I would say it's better to train monday, tuesday, wednesday, skip thursday, friday, saturday, skip sunday.